# Synchronize Jira Attachments to Confluence Page

Tags: jira, confluence

I am relatively new to the atlassian world and I am tasked with synchronizing pdf attachments (but not attachments of other types) of an issue in a certain jira project to a page on confluence. I only found means to do this manually (e.g.: [see here](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/confluence/display-jira-issues-in-confluence-more-power-more-control)), which is not what I am looking for.

Any help pointing me in the right direction to solve this is highly apprechiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that downloads and uploads the desired attachments via the REST API of Jira/Confluence.

1. Get PDF attachments for specific issue:

   ```
   GET {jiraBaseUrl}/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}

   //returns:
   {
     ...
     "key": "EX-1",
     "fields": {
       ...
       "attachment": [
           {
              ...
               "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
               "content": "http://www.example.com/jira/attachments/10000",
               ...
           }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

   Where "fields > attachment > mimeType" in the result should be checked for `application/pdf` and "fields > attachment > content" is the URL to download the attachment. Source: [Jira REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.1.0/#api/2/issue-getIssue)
2. Upload the attachment to Confluence

   ```
   POST {confluenceBaseUrl}/rest/api/content/{pageId}/child/attachment

   //e.g.:
   curl -D- -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@myfile.txt" -F "comment=This is my File" http://myhost/rest/api/content/123/child/attachment
   ```

   Check the documentation for a complete curl example: [Confluence REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/rest/6.15.4/#api/content/%7Bid%7D/child/attachment-createAttachments)

With these two REST resources you should be able to automate your task. For authentication you can start with a simple [basic authentication header](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/).